# Access dynamic key in javascript object

Tags: javascript

Im  not sure if im asking the right question, but here it goes. I am hitting an API and getting an javascript object that looks like the following

```
x: {
  id: 1,
  username: 'Ryan',
  picture: 151
}
```

Im storing this object in a myObj const. I want to access the data inside x, but the issue is each time I hit the API x changes names. The object keys inside x remain the same, but sometimes x is y, a, l, b, etc.

Right now Im trying

```
myObj.x
```

but once x is y, I would have to change it to myObj.y instead. How can I access the properties inside this dynamic object?

SOLUTION:

```
myObj[Object.keys(myObj)[0]]
```

Comment: If at any given time, there is only one key ie., either x, y, a etc you can do myObj[Object.keys(myObj)[0]]

Comment: What exactly you are getting when you hit the API..?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because author has found a solution.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Self answering questions is encouraged. But the solution should be an answer, not be in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to test the property which contains a subproperty id

```
var obj = {
  a: {
      id: 1,
      username: 'Ryan',
      picture: 151
    },
  b: {
      ident: 2,
      firstName: 'jim',
      movie: 321
    }
};

var x = obj[Object.keys(obj).filter(item => obj[item].id)];
console.log(x); // { id: 1, username: 'Ryan', picture: 151 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use `Object.keys(myObj)[0]` if there is more than one key, because the order of the returned array is implementation dependent.

Instead, you should use something like

```
var x = getCurrentPropertyName(); // "x"
// ...
myObj[x];
```

Where `getCurrentPropertyName` somehow returns the current name of the desired property. If you have no way to know that, you have a serious problem with your code.